# How to handle that "Local Time to UTC Conversion" differently implemented in .NET / java

Tags: java, .net, json, datetime, utc

**.NET Web Service**
I have a .NET web service which returns json formatted DateTime's.
The json representation of a DateTime specified by Microsoft is for example:
/Date(1302847200000+0200)/
This is according to [MSDN - Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) the millisecond offset since the first of January 1970 in UTC before the +/- sign and after the sign the time zone offset of the local time to GMT. So for this serialization the DateTime value must be converted from the web service's local time to UTC.

**Android (java) Client**
In my Android application, which receives the web service results, I parse json using Gson. Because the .NET DateTime json serialization is not a standard (according to Microsoft there is no such standard for DateTime) gson is not able to parse such formatted dates. I wrote a Date TypeAdapter which does the serialization and deserialization on the client side.

So this seems to work fine. DateTime exchange from and to service in UTC. It would be fine, if .NET's DateTime and Java's Calendar would regard totally the same rules when it comes to conversion of local to UTC time.

**An example:** Switzerland has DST (Daylight Saving Time) since 1979. Java knows that DST did not exist before. .NET assumes it exists since ever. So when a date in summer before 1979 is converted from .NET to UTC and from Java back to Local time (for presentation), then this date loses an hour in the same time zone.

**Question**
How to face that problem? Is there any mistake I am doing in the described data exchange.
I thought about many different solutions. The only way which i can imagine to work properly is to replace the .NET json DateTime Serialization/Deserialization. This of course is not a favoured one...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not just ignore the timezone offset if .NET is getting it wrong? If it gives you milliseconds since epoch in UTC, that should be all you need to work with.

Comment: No @Alex, that will be off by a factor of whatever the timezone difference is.

Comment: @Hexxagonal not necessarily, it depends on the application. You have to do conversion between UTC and local timezone either at both ends or at neither. If you can get away with it, it's better to always work with UTC because of issues like this.

Comment: The UTCNow calls are also faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the standard .NET Json serializer it will cause you too many headaches than you need if you are working between Java and .NET.  As you found out, Microsoft uses a format that most people don't use.

The best serializer is [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) ([NuGet page](http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)) it's become a de facto standard for .NET developers.  They have a great DateTime serialization/deserialization options that are simple to use.  [For more information check out their blog post on DateTime](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx).  I tend to use ISO 8601, which is their default format in Json.NET v4.5.

I used to work on an enterprise application that worked communicated via Json with many different products create in a range of languages and Json.NET made that inter-product communication trivial.

**Update on dealing with Switzerland's DateTime**

Since you're specifying a generic Central European Standard Time, .NET doesn't know what Switzerland's date time rules are specifically.  To deal with Switzerland you're going to need to give .NET the Switzerland rules.  Looking at Wikipedia it started in 1981, so creating a custom `TimeZoneInfo` would look something like the following:

```
// UTC Time
var date1 = new DateTime(1969, 4, 20, 2, 20,00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine("Date 1: " + date1.ToString() + " - " + date1.IsDaylightSavingTime());

// CEST
var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var date2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date1, timezone);
Console.WriteLine("Date 2: " + date2.ToString() + " - " + date2.IsDaylightSavingTime() + " " + timezone.IsAmbiguousTime(date2));

// Switzerland
var cesAdjRule = timezone.GetAdjustmentRules().Single();
var switzerlandStartTransition = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(
        cesAdjRule.DaylightTransitionStart.TimeOfDay,
        cesAdjRule.DaylightTransitionStart.Month, cesAdjRule.DaylightTransitionStart.Week,
        cesAdjRule.DaylightTransitionStart.DayOfWeek
);
var switzerlandAdjustmentRule = TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.CreateAdjustmentRule(
    new DateTime(1981, 1, 1),
    DateTime.MaxValue.Date,
    cesAdjRule.DaylightDelta,
    switzerlandStartTransition,
    cesAdjRule.DaylightTransitionEnd
);
TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] adjustments = {switzerlandAdjustmentRule};

var switzerlandTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Switzerland",
                                                            timezone.BaseUtcOffset,
                                                            "Switzerland",
                                                            "Switzerland",
                                                            "Switzerland",
                                                            adjustments, false);

var date3 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, timezone, switzerlandTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine("Date 3: " + date3.ToString() + " - " + date3.IsDaylightSavingTime() + " " + timezone.IsAmbiguousTime(date3));
```

The output of that would look like this (at least on my machine):

```
Date 1: 4/20/1969 2:20:00 AM - False
Date 2: 4/20/1969 4:20:00 AM - True - False
Date 3: 4/20/1969 3:20:00 AM - True - False
```

As you can see, IsDaylightSavingsTime is True on the `DateTime`, but `TimeZoneInfo` correctly converted our time.  Trying a few other combinations looks good too.  You can also convert between the CEST that it thinks you have and Switzerland with `TimeZoneInfo.CovertTime()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i am checking the links you provided and will mark it as an answer, if that really works. :)

Comment: I checked this library and this is really a little gold nugget :). I am not sure if it solves my problem. The good thing about the library is it uses a better format using ISO 8601. Nevertheless it still uses the standard DateTime.ToUniversalTime() method. The problem is that this implementation is not the same as the java. The difference I mentioned about DST. So the universal time i am parsing back on the client side will still loose an hour. What do you think about let the server send the time in it's local time and then to all the conversion on the client side?

Comment: Ok, updated a bit. I think you should be able to get this now.

Comment: You really made me a happy day! Thank you for this detailed solution and explanation on this difficult topic. I did not consider that it is possible to influence the dst rules.

Comment: It wasn't possible until a few years ago.  I remember a few years ago having to hand code complex DST rules in... this is way nicer.